# NoSuchMethodError at getDrawable in Android Studio Project

Tags: android, eclipse

I am following some tutorials on the book and my codes looks fine because I didn't got any error. But when I try to run my application I got these errors:

```
02-04 15:22:29.379: E/Trace(10992): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
02-04 15:22:29.379: D/ActivityThread(10992): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
02-04 15:22:29.389: D/ActivityThread(10992): setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
02-04 15:22:29.389: D/ActivityThread(10992): setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
02-04 15:22:29.429: W/dalvikvm(10992): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 15273: Lcom/example/silentmodetoggle/MainActivity;.getDrawable (I)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
02-04 15:22:29.429: W/dalvikvm(10992): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 15273: Lcom/example/silentmodetoggle/MainActivity;.getDrawable (I)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
02-04 15:22:29.479: W/dalvikvm(10992): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41540438)
02-04 15:22:29.479: E/AndroidRuntime(10992): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-04 15:22:29.479: E/AndroidRuntime(10992): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.example.silentmodetoggle.MainActivity.getDrawable
02-04 15:22:29.479: E/AndroidRuntime(10992):    at com.example.silentmodetoggle.MainActivity.toggleUi(MainActivity.java:75)
02-04 15:22:29.479: E/AndroidRuntime(10992):    at com.example.silentmodetoggle.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:88)
02-04 15:22:29.479: E/AndroidRuntime(10992):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1187)
02-04 15:22:29.479: E/AndroidRuntime(10992):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5314)
02-04 15:22:29.479: E/AndroidRuntime(10992):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2578)
02-04 15:22:29.479: E/AndroidRuntime(10992):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2616)
02-04 15:22:29.479: E/AndroidRuntime(10992):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2102)
02-04 15:22:29.479: E/AndroidRuntime(10992):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:137)
02-04 15:22:29.479: E/AndroidRuntime(10992):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1203)
02-04 15:22:29.479: E/AndroidRuntime(10992):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-04 15:22:29.479: E/AndroidRuntime(10992):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-04 15:22:29.479: E/AndroidRuntime(10992):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4863)
02-04 15:22:29.479: E/AndroidRuntime(10992):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-04 15:22:29.479: E/AndroidRuntime(10992):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-04 15:22:29.479: E/AndroidRuntime(10992):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
02-04 15:22:29.479: E/AndroidRuntime(10992):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
02-04 15:22:29.479: E/AndroidRuntime(10992):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I don't know what part did I go wrong.

Here's my code:

```
package com.example.silentmodetoggle;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private AudioManager mAudioManager;
    private boolean mPhoneIsSilent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       mAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);

       checkIfPhoneIsSilent();
       setButtonClickListener();

    }

    private void setButtonClickListener() {

         Button toggleButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
         toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(mPhoneIsSilent) {
                    //change back to normal mode
                    mAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
                    mPhoneIsSilent = false;
                } else {
                    //Change to silent mode
                    mAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
                    mPhoneIsSilent = true;
                }

                //Now toggle the UI again
                toggleUi();

            }
        });

    }

    /*
     * Checks to see  if the phone is currently in silent mode
     */
    private void checkIfPhoneIsSilent() {
        int ringerMode = mAudioManager.getRingerMode();
        if(ringerMode == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT) {
            mPhoneIsSilent = true;
        } else {
            mPhoneIsSilent = false;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Toggles the UI images from silent to normal and vice versa
     */
    private void toggleUi() {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.phone_icon);
        Drawable newPhoneImage;

        if(mPhoneIsSilent) {
            newPhoneImage = getDrawable(R.drawable.phone_silent);
        } else {
            newPhoneImage = getDrawable(R.drawable.phone_on);
        }

        imageView.setImageDrawable(newPhoneImage);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        checkIfPhoneIsSilent();
        toggleUi();
    }

}
```

I am running on API 23 and I am using Eclipse for this. Can you help me identify what part is my error. I am new in Android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getDrawable(resid)` was deprecated in API 21 in favor of `getDrawable(resid, theme);`

Try this,

```
private Drawable getDrawableResource(int resID) {
    return ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, resID);
}
```

Then in your code,

```
if(mPhoneIsSilent) {
    newPhoneImage = getDrawableResource(R.drawable.phone_silent);
} else {
    newPhoneImage = getDrawableResource(R.drawable.phone_on);
}
```

`ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, resID)` is equivalent to calling,

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    return resources.getDrawable(resID, context.getTheme());
} else {
    return resources.getDrawable(resID);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Ok Ill try.

Comment: Ok I changed my code but I have an error with this line `return getResources().getDrawable(resID, getTheme());` and also to this `return getResources().getDrawable(resID);` my error says `Call requires API level 21 (current min is 8): android.content.res.Resources#getDrawable`

Comment: @Jerielle that is fine. The `if` condition takes care of that.

Comment: Ok the error is in the `else` part which is `return getResources().getDrawable(resID);` I can't run the app because of this error.

Comment: Wow it's working now. Thanks for the help. I'll study now how the code works. :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Thanks again. Sometimes I am confuse because the tutorial I am following is using an old API.

Answer (score 3):

This is where your code crashes:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.example.silentmodetoggle.MainActivity.getDrawable

You should call getDrawable on the resources object:
getResources().getDrawable(

Answer (score 1):

Edit this method only :-

```
 private void toggleUi() {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        if(mPhoneIsSilent) {
            imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img1));
        } else {
            imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img2));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried and it says `The method getDrawable(int) from the type Resources is deprecated`

Comment: just change your toggleUi() to this code. definitely work else comment here.